# ActionLink and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I am using [jQuery Pagination plugin](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/).

In order to configure URLs I need to set `href` attribute.

```
$(selector).twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 35,
    visiblePages: 8,
    href: '?page={{number}}'
});
```

How can I assign `Ajax.ActionLink()` for `href` ?

```
$(#someid).twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 35,
        visiblePages: 8,
        href: '@Ajax.ActionLink(
                "{{number}}", 
                "Action", 
                "Controller", 
                new {page = "{{number}}"}, 
                new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST"})'});
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not like that. That will render an actual form element, you want the url helper

```
$(#someid).twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 35,
    visiblePages: 8,
    href: "@(Url.Action("actionName","controllerName"))"+'?page={{number}}'
```

Comment: I was able to do it Url.Action(), but Ajax.ActionLink() does not work.